# Initializing from an array of property pointers

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, pointers

I'm trying to write a shortcut for initializing my custom UIView's properties, rather than write out each one line by line, but unfortunately it's not working the way I expected.

```
    // .h file
    @property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *view1;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *view2;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *view3;
    @property (nonatomic, strong) UIView *view4;

    // .m file
    UIView *views[] = { self.view1, self.view2, self.view3, self.view4 };
    for ( int i = 0; i < sizeof(views) / sizeof(views[0]); i++ ) {
        views[i] = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.frame];
    }

    NSLog( @"%@", self.view1 ); // prints null
```

Is this just not allowed with C-style arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your initialization of `views[]` looks fine, but as soon as you do

```
views[i] = ...
```

you are merely overwriting the contents of the array. You are, however, *not* initializing `self.view1`, `self.view2`, etc. Try

```
NSLog(@"%@", views[0]);
```

to see what I mean.

I would not do it like follows, but you *could* probably do (untested):

```
UIView **views[] = { &self.view1, &self.view2, &self.view3, &self.view4 };
for (int i = 0; i < (sizeof(views) / sizeof(views[0]); ++i)
{
    *views[i] = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame: self.frame];
}

NSLog(@"%@", self.view1);
```

I would rather initialize them one by one, without the array. I don't see any advantage in using an array and a loop.

Comment: I agree with Rudy. Alternatively, if they're all so similar, perhaps you could just have `@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *arrayOfSimilarViews;` Then just iterate from `0` to `n` and add an extra view to the array each time.

Comment: @AaronBrager: agreed.

Comment: This approach seems fragile and depends on how the property is implemented. A solution that actually sets the property would be better.

Comment: Sure, a solution that actually sets the property would certainly be better. I said it was untested, and that I would not do it like this, but if it must be done in a loop, this seems to answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

You are just changing the pointer inside the array, the self.view1 pointer will still point to nil.

You could have an array of views as property:

```
@property(nonatomic,strong) UIView **views;
```

Or maybe you can use [Key Value Coding](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/Articles/KeyValueCoding.html) like

```
for(int i=1;i<5;i++){
    NSString* key = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"view%i",i];
    UIView *view = //initialize view
    [self setValue:view forKey:key];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Calling e.g. `self.view1` at the beginning will give you `nil` before you have initialized it. So the line

```
UIView *views[] = { self.view1, self.view2, self.view3, self.view4 };
```

is effectively creating an array of 4 `nil`s.

Inserting the new instances of `UIView` to the array afterwards has no effect on the properties. In fact, a property is only a pair of selectors (e.g. `view1` and `setView1:`) and by itself cannot be used reliably with C-style pointers.

You **could** use the backing ivars with an array of `UIView **` pointers, but you're most likely better off rethinking the whole approach.